# How to setup a testing system for different platforms and different baselines

Tags: automated-testing, windows, git

I need to setup a testing system for my company. Currently we are doing the following:

- Build all baselines (latest, stable, customised1, customised2), just the binaries
- Test those binaries on two times two systems (Windows-7 and Windows-x)

The testdata are equal on every system (which is not desired).

Therefore I'm looking to solve the following situation:

- Build all baselines, based on GIT branches.
- Create installers for all baselines (configuration might depend on baseline).
- Install and test each baseline/platform individually (testdata might depend on baseline).

This however comes down to the following table:

```
        | Latest | Stable | Customised1 | Customised2
--------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------
W7      |      x |      x |           x |           x
Vista   |      x |      x |           x |           x
WServer |      x |      x |           x |           x
W8      |      x |      x |           x |           x
W10     |      x |      x |           x |           x
```

In order to perform those tests, until now we've always been working with virtual machines over an ESX server.

As you can derive from the table, we would need up to 20 virtual machines, and I'm wondering is there any kind of technology which makes it possible to reduce this number? (Is there any kind of technology which can emulate different Windows-x PCs and execute the tests for the different baselines simultaneously?)

Comment: Nobody has an idea?

Comment: "Is there any kind of technology which can emulate different Windows-x PCs and execute the tests for the different baselines simultaneously?" - multiple simultaneous VMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any kind of technology which can emulate different Windows-x
>   PCs and execute the tests for the different baselines simultaneously?

Yes, first you need to setup the machines with virtualisation software. E.g. VMWare, VirtualBox or [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software). For some systems you might use cloud hosting, for others you probably need your own servers to host the VMs as not much cloud-providers support desktop operating systems.

Next you setup remote access to all the machines. Then you configure a [build-server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software) script to login to the machines, do any setup, execute the tests and send back the results to a central location.

Now configure the build-server to run all the operating version in parallel and you are done.

No, there is not a full product that does all this for you. Also I wonder what the risks are of something not working on all the Windows version. Maybe just test the high risks parts and not everything.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of automated testing are you doing?  Depending on the answer, there may be products that can do this for you (not sure if that's an option, or if you need it all in house).  For instance [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/platforms) looks to have everything from Windows 10 down to XP, with multiple versions of the major browsers.

Comment: This is nice for web application testing, not desktops. Not sure what the OP needs though.